# как правильно использовать includes с enum в TS

Tags: typescript

есть такой код:

```
enum EEnum {
    A = 'A'
}

type EType = keyof typeof EEnum

let value: EType = EEnum.A

if (value === EEnum.A) {
    // norm
}

if ([EEnum.A].includes(value)) {
    // Argument of type '"A"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EEnum'.(2345)
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAoj7QN4CgpqgQSgXigcgz2QF9lkAXATwAdhYAVGu3Aa2EoHsAzKK272PEhkANsHJQAbgEMRYYAC4GTHIIQA6DGQCWPABQy5zbLjgaMASigp0UAPR2oIDgCcIJHfoDaZyJoC66togAMZyACbAAM4GsvIWVjboDpguAOaQoBICfHR4AEQY%20XhQ2lFOHBLSUVHaaSDSAEZivBxQ1NIu0hDiwC5QOSp4vhB46noATADMACwArBYeaEA)

Сравнение через '===' TS пропускает, но через includes - нет

Подскажите, как правильно использовать includes с enum`ами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно либо указать тип `EEnum` для value (а не тип ключей `string`):

```
enum EEnum {
    A = 'A'
}

let value: EEnum = EEnum.A

if (value === EEnum.A) {
    // norm
}

if ( [EEnum.A].includes(value)) {
    // Argument of type '"A"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EEnum'.(2345)
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAoj7QN4CgpqgQSgXigcgz2QF9lkAbYAFygDcBDcsYALlnkh3YQDoMyAlgDMoACgZNgObLji8MASigp0UAPRqoIAPYAnCCUEjRUANpzIfALo8BIAMZMAJsADO4xswVKV6DZl0Ac0hQGm0RKgBPAAcpPAAiDHi8KAFXLW0aeldXAUCQegAjSigqbSho%20l16CGpgXShw0pi4iwg8HlEAJgBmABYAVgVDIA)

, либо указать, что у вас массив строк:

```
enum EEnum {
    A = 'A'
}

type EType = keyof typeof EEnum

let value: EType = EEnum.A

if (value === EEnum.A) {
    // norm
}

let arr: string[] = [EEnum.A]

if ( arr.includes(value)) {
    // Argument of type '"A"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EEnum'.(2345)
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAoj7QN4CgpqgQSgXigcgz2QF9lkAXATwAdhYAVGu3Aa2EoHsAzKK272PEhkANsHJQAbgEMRYYAC4GTHIIQA6DGQCWPABQy5zbLjgaMASigp0UAPR2oIDgCcIJUeKjSXLpQGdyF20QAHMAbQBdVXCzSE1InX1vX3UQgGM5ABNgfwNZeQsrG3QHTBdQyFAJAT46PAAiDAa8KG1-Jw4JaX9-bVCQaQAjMV4OKGofaQhxYBcoWpU8OIg8dT0AJgBmABYAVgsPNCA)

Comment: вообще, автор перемудрил в вопросе. достаточно заменить `let value: EType = EEnum.A` на `let value = EEnum.A`

Comment: @nörbörnën возможно. Я например почти никогда не использую автоматический вывод типов, потому что при этом уменьшается вероятность отловить ошибку, то есть код становится похож на js.